# Are code statements that are outside the synchronized statement thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

```
public void addName(String name) {
    synchronized(this) {
        lastName = name;
        nameCount++;
    }
    nameList.add(name);
    doA();
    doB();
}
```

Following the java document's example above, the "nameList.add(name);doA();doB();" are thread-safe ?

Comment: I think you can answer this yourself with a little common sense. What is the purpose of creating a `synchronized` block in the first place? Why do you use `synchronized`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Only:

`synchronized(this) {
        lastName = name;
        nameCount++;
    }`

Is shown to be threadsafe here.

doA() and doB() could have additional locking though, but may be called multiple times which could have unintended side effects.